# Java: convert string to double\long, divide by 100 and convert it back to string (SpEL)

Tags: java, type-conversion, spring-el

This is what I have:

A string var `amount` with value: `"123.45"`.

What I need is to divide it by 100 on a SpEL expression. So I went like this:

```
T(java.lang.Double).valueOf(amount) / 100D
```

And then, return the result as a string again.

How can I achieve it? I tried

```
T(java.lang.Double).toString(T(java.lang.Double).valueOf(amount) / 100D)
```

but is not working. And instead of dividing is multipling for some reason :-\

Thanks in advance

Comment: _Multiply_ by 100 to receive cents: 12345? Or truncate to finally receive 123?

Answer (score 1):

Consider, You have a variable named **amount**

```
String amount = "123.45";
//The following code converts 123.45 into Double and divides it by 100
Double dividedValue = new Double(Double.valueOf(amount)/100);  
//To convert the resultant double value into String
String resultantValue = dividedValue.toString();
```

Hope, it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the adjusted double to a string using `String#valueOf`:

```
T(java.lang.String).valueOf(T(java.lang.Double).valueOf(amount) / 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full [explanation](https://www.java67.com/2015/06/how-to-convert-string-to-double-java-example.html) about convertion in double and back to String.

A possibility is

```
double myValue = 88.22;
String doubled = String.valueOf(myValue);
```

And the toString() method is a possibility to transfer it back.